# Delete "Reply to this comment" line: Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm attempting to write a macro to automatically delete all "Reply to this comment" lines in a Word doc.

I can't figure out how to Find-Replace the entire line (including the paragraph mark).

The ASCII code for the paragraph mark is ^013.

The source text is typically copied from a blog post into Word similar to below.

[image]

Comment: Can you show or  share an image of the word doc?

Comment: "`Reply to this comment^p`” its listed in the special characters https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/661-replace-hard-returns-with-soft-returns.html#a1

Comment: @Slai - That was the first thing I tried and it didn't work.

The error dialog box pops up and says, "Word has finished searching the document. The search item was not found." Using the ^p works on its own, but does not work in conjunction with other text.

Comment: @SeanS sounds like there might be some non-printable characters before `^p`. You can try with wildcards `comment*^p` https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/word-delete-tabs-and-page-numbers-from-the-end-of-a-paragraph/

Comment: @Slai - I also couldn't get the allow wildcards to work either, but I figured out a workaround by replacing "Reply to this comment" and then deleting one character, which is the ^p. VBA code is listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is below. It counts occurrences, then loops through the text deleting the phrase and paragraph mark as it goes:

```
Sub DeleteReplyComments()
  ' loop through lines to count Replies
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    MyDoc = ActiveDocument.Range.Text
    txt = "Reply to this comment"
    t = Replace(MyDoc, txt, "")
    nCount = (Len(MyDoc) - Len(t)) / Len(txt)
  ' delete Replies and ^p's
    For i = 1 To nCount
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "Reply to this comment"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute
        Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdParagraph
        Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Next i
End Sub
```